# TypeLoadException when using Newtonsoft.Json inside of a PCL

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, portable-class-library

I'm facing a blocking problem...
I have a project (iOS, in this case), referencing a PCL (made by me), which itself references Newtonsoft.Json portable version

App --> My PCL --> Newtonsoft.Json

Everything compiles just fine, but at runtime, when using a method of my PCL which calls Newtonsoft.Json, I get a TypeLoadException

Example:
A simple PCL, referencing Newtonsoft.Json Portable, with a single class like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int Test() {
        var json = @"{""t"":16,""s"":""test""}";
        var o = JObject.Parse(json);
        return o["t"].Value<int>();
    }
}
```

A simple App, with a single button, with this event handler:

```
partial void Test() {
    var c = new MyClass();
    var i = c.Test();
    new UIAlertView("", i.ToString(), null, "Close").Show();
}
```

I get a TypeLoadException when tapping the button, on line "var i = c.Test();" !

Even weirder, when replacing this:

```
return o["t"].Value<int>();
```

with this:

```
return (int)o["t"];
```

I'm not getting a TypeLoadException anymore, but a MissingMemberException, with this message:

> Missing method Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken::op_Explicit(JToken) in
>   assembly
>   /Users/Ingham/Projects/TestPCL-iOS/TestPCL-iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.dll,
>   referenced in assembly
>   /Users/Ingham/Projects/TestPCL-iOS/TestPCL/bin/Debug/TestPCL.dll

I really can't see what I'm doing wrong...

I've tried many combinations of possible profiles for my PCL, but nothing works...

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance !

You can download the sample project here (Xamarin.iOS) : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsclrg5d1cor1dk/TestPCL.zip

Comment: post the stack and error message from the TypeLoadException

Comment: did you even manage to solve this?